# How To get url parameter from url in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get parameter from url.
Following is my url.
I wnt to get "uid" parameter from my url.

```
http://localhost:8080/mydemoproject/#/tables/view?uid=71
```

Comment: `window.location.search` will contain `?uid=71` - hope that helps - oops, sorry, no ... `window.location.hash` will contain `#/tables/view?uid=71`

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please read the [tour] and [ask].   You might also like to read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Literally: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+To+get+url+parameter+from+url+in+jquery%3F gives you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
window.location.href.split("=")[1]
```

Comment: Answer will give Only first parameter. if there is more parameters in url it doesnt work.

Comment: @Sindhoor "if" can many things so "if" and "if" is should not consider in this context.

Comment: i like programmer like you.

Comment: @Sindhoor this is dose not matter you like anyone or not. I just tried to answer what the need question owner and it is giving perfect result in this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Try solving these problems with RegEx

```
let myURL = window.location.href; // "http://localhost:8080/mydemoproject/#/tables/view?uid=71"
let myRegexp = /uid=(\d*)/i;
let match = myRegexp.exec(myURL);
if (match !== null) {
  console.log(match[1]); // 71
}
```

A condensed version would look like this

```
let match = /uid=(\d*)/i.exec(window.location.href);
let uidValue = (match !== null ? match[1] : undefined);
console.log(uidValue); // 71
```

Comment: url should be static? and shouldnt change? also the parameter should be same always? evrytime he should use different functions to get different parameters?

Comment: Why do you downvote every answer? This answer is as legit as your answer is. The question was how to detect the uid parameter not how to detect any parameter.

Answer (score -1):

On page load call the function "`get_param('uid');`"
And paste this code into your document.

```
<script type= "text/javascript" >

    function get_param(param) {
        var vars = {};
        window.location.href.replace(location.hash, '').replace(
        /[?&]+([^=&]+)=?([^&]*)?/gi, // regexp
        function (m, key, value) { // callback
            vars[key] = value !== undefined ? value : '';
        }
    );
    alert(vars[param]);
    }
</script>
```